# Location of the point on Earth with the Sun at the zenith

Tags: geography, astronomy

This should be an easy question, but I don't know the correct syntax.
I'm trying to create an animation based on NightHemisphere during a year. For each day, the instant correspond to the time of the Sunset at Paris
Looking on previous answers, I have constructed this function that works:

```
f := Function[x, DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}] + Quantity[(x - 1), "Days"]];
tg = Table[Show[
    GeoGraphics[
     NightHemisphere[
      Sunset[GeoPosition[{48.858042`, 2.2910492`}], DateObject[f[n]], 
       TimeZone -> +1]], GeoRange -> "World", 
     GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, 0}]],
    ImageSize -> Large], {n, 1, 365}];
Export["sunset_paris.gif", tg]
```

Now I want to add a disk representing the position of the Earth place just below the Sun at that time, as it appears in, for instance, in https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html
but I don't know how to transform SunPosition[] or other function to the position of this place. SunPosition gives the astronomical position of the Sun as seen from a location, while I'm looking for a point on Earth.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Instead of `f := Function[x, DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}] + Quantity[(x - 1), "Days"]]` you can simply write `f[x_] := DayPlus[{2022, 1, 1}, x - 1]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks, @Roman, I'm new to the DateObject syntax and I didn't know that you can write the 56th of January.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused; when I run Jose's excellent answer ((https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264104/79614)) the sublunar plot behaves as expected, but the subsolar disk seems to make a straight line in stead of the expected sinusoid (from tropic to tropic since we considere a whole year). Is there something I am not seeing right? Cheers, Pieter

Answer (score 2):

We can compute those locations as follows:

```
subSolarPoint[date_] := GeoPosition[Reverse[SunPosition[date, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"] - {SiderealTime[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], date], 0}]]

subLunarPoint[date_] := GeoPosition[Reverse[MoonPosition[date, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"] - {SiderealTime[GeoPosition[{0, 0}], date], 0}]]
```

Then evaluate:

```
paris = GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}]];

sunsets = Table[
   Sunset[paris, DateObject[{2022, 1, n}, TimeZone -> 1]],
   {n, 1, 365}
];

tg = Table[
    GeoGraphics[{
        NightHemisphere[s],
        GeoStyling[Yellow], GeoDisk[subSolarPoint[s], Quantity[100, "Miles"]], 
        GeoStyling[Black],  GeoDisk[subLunarPoint[s], Quantity[100, "Miles"]]
    }, GeoRange -> "World", ImageSize -> Large],
    {s, sunsets}
];

ListAnimate[tg]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First provide a latitude at which you want your disk (representing the sun) to locate on your plots - let say at $x^\circ\;\mathrm{N}$. And I'm going to define a function:

```
zenithPole[n_] := QuantityMagnitude[
    First@SunPosition[GeoPosition[{90, 0}], DateObject[{2022, 1, n}, TimeZone -> 1]]
]

(*at 2022-01-01 00:00*)
zenithPole[1]

(* 344.18 *)
```

which outputs the azimuth angle of the sun, seen from the north pole `GeoPosition[{90, 0}]`, at time `{DateObject[{2022, 1, n}, TimeZone -> 1}`. And I will subtract this from `360 (*degree*)`, then that's the longitude of every geoposition in which the zenith is. To see for yourself if this is true,

```
zenith[x_,n_] := SunPosition[
    GeoPosition[{x, 360 - zenithPole[n]}]
, DateObject[{2022, 1, n}, TimeZone -> 1]]

(*at 2022-01-01 00:00*)
zenith[0,1] (*at the equator*)
zenith[2.2910492`,1] (*at E 2.2910492`*)

(*
  {180.00°, -66.98°}
  {180.00°, -69.27°}
*)
```

As you can see, the sun is right at the zenith. So the location you want is `GeoPosition[{x, 360 - zenithPole[n]}]`, where the `x` is the latitude where you want your disk to be at.